# Binding in DataTemplate/ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, styles

I have a ComboBox whose ItemSource is a ListCollectionView of MyClass. The ComboBox uses the following ItemTemplate:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleComboBoxGroups" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <BulletDecorator VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Ellipse Margin="3,0,0,0" Width="4" Height="4"/>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlock}" Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </BulletDecorator>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

MyClass exposes two properties:

public sealed class MyClass
{
    public MyEnum Property1 { get; set; }
    public String Property2 { get; set; }
}

I'm trying to figure out how to make the TextBlock.Foreground color depending on Property1. For the moment I tried these to no avail:

```
Foreground="{Binding Property1, Converter=MyEnumToColorConverter}"
Foreground="{Binding Converter=MyEnumToColorConverter, Path=Property1}"
Foreground="{Binding Converter=MyEnumToColorConverter, Path=Property1, Source={Binding}}"
```

But I always get an Exception. How can I bind to the ComboBox item properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a resource that will be an instance of your converter.

```
<Style.Resources>
    <namespace:MyEnumToColorConverter x:Key="MyEnumToColorConverter" />
</Style.Resources>
```

… then use that resource in your binding:

```
Foreground="{Binding Property1, Converter={StaticResource MyEnumToColorConverter}}"
```

---

An alternative is to reference your converter statically, in which case you will not need to create a resource instance. Turn your converter into a singleton:

```
public class MyEnumColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private MyEnumColorConverter() { }

     private static IValueConverter _instance;
     public static IValueConverter Instance
     {
          get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new MyEnumColorConverter); }
     }

     // implement IValueConverter

}
```

In XAML you will reference it like this:

```
Foreground="{Binding Property1, Converter={x:Static namespace:MyEnumColorConverter.Instance}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you in fact have a converter of type `MyEnumToColorConverter`, then in order to use it in a binding, you'll need to first declare an instance of it. Typically, you'll do that in the `Resources` section of the parent control (or style,) something like:

```
<Style.Resources>
    <myNamespace:MyEnumToColorConverter x:Key="EnumToColorConverter" />
</Style.Resources>
```

Then, you can reference it with a `StaticResource` markup extension:

```
Foreground="{Binding Path=Property1, Converter={StaticResource EnumToColorConverter}}"
```